# How to use withRouter() with a generic component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a component like this:

```
function GenericComponent<T>(props: RouteComponentProps) {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(GenericComponent)
```

When attempting to use it with `<GenericComponent<SomeModel> />`, I get the following error:

> Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

How do I pass `T` to withRouter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can't do that way, I think you can do by having a function working as a factory with takes generic `T` then return the component with that type as following:

```js
function GenericComponent<T>(props: RouteComponentProps<T>) {
  // ...
}

export function factory<T>() {
  return withRouter((props: RouteComponentProps<T>) => (
    <GenericComponent<T> {...props} />
  ));
}

// Usage
function App() {
  const FooWithId = factory<{ id: string }>();

  return (
    <FooWithId />
  )
}
```